# Multiple cron jobs not working

Tags: php, cron

I am new to cron jobs.

The first cron job is running, but the second is not running.

```
   /usr/bin/php -q /home/domain/public_html/cronjob_posting.php

   /usr/bin/php -q /home/domain/public_html/cronjob_deletepost.php
```

Please help me.

Comment: You have to call each and every page in your hosting server?

Comment: What is your cron entry - Can you paste the output of `crontab -l` here? Also, does the second command gives correct output from commandline?

Answer (score -1):

You can combine multiple jobs by adding them to cron in the following way:

1) personally I prefer editing in gedit

```
sudo gedit ~/.profile
```

2) Add or edit these 2 lines

```
export VISUAL="gedit"
export EDITOR="gedit"
```

3) logout and login

4) Then in terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

5) Add these lines:

```
0 0 * * * /home/domain/public_html/cronjob_posting.php
0 0 * * * /home/domain/public_html/cronjob_deletepost.php
```

[Every day at 0:00 AM the server will run these scripts]

6) Then check if everything is there:

```
crontab -l
```

Comment: where i write sudo gedit ~/.profile ,export VISUAL="gedit"
export EDITOR="gedit" , crontab -e

Comment: That would be in the terminal if you are using Linux

Comment: -1 for suggesting gedit. Usually, crons are scheduled on servers, and one doesn't have access to gedit on servers, unless using `ssh` with `x server` or something similar. Also, the php scripts will most likely fail by themselves unless they follow adequate configuration.